# Expression evaluation an error in programming

Tags: c++, expression

Evaluating the expression
2+*3/2++
The compiler is giving errors
Error   1   error C2100: illegal indirection

Error   2   error C2105: '++' needs l-value 
    IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

    IntelliSense: operand of '*' must be a pointer

Can someone explain me these please.

Comment: Increment operator cannot be applied to numbers

Comment: ya, googling the error messages could explain all three, and also it would help if you had learnt the language to a basic extent before blindly hammerin' code into the IDE.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will research on it more!

Comment: I am a newbie in C++ can someone explain errors in easy way i have googled them but can't understand the errors clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ++ operator can not be used on a number.

```
2++
```

does not make sense. It would be the same as assign the value 3 to 2, like

```
2 = 3  // Can't do that
```

You need a variable to use ++

```
int a;
a = 2;
a++;   // Now a holds the value 3
```